# CiviCRM old version

Tags: version

If an old version of CiviCRM is installed on my wordpress site, are there dangers to the website?
eg security dangers, site malfunctioning etc.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are on at least the most recent security release then your site contains known security vulnerabilities (currently 5.35.2 / 5.36.1 - see [release notes](https://civicrm.org/blog/tags/release)).  However, whether those vulnerabilities are actually exploitable on your system depends on many factors, but it's a bad place to be.

You may also encounter other problems - for example if your hosting upgrades the version of php to something more recent than your version of CiviCRM can cope with.

What is stopping you upgrading to the current version?